# Creating a collapsible and sortable ASP.Net web table using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I am stack trying to make this table collapse like this one:

https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/styling/bootstrap.html

Anything I tried so far was not working. I tried to use bootstrap examples with no success.

The following code is the code for the table:

```html
<div class="table-responsive" style="border: 0; border-radius: 15px; padding-bottom: 35px">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="SystemUpTimeUpdatePanel" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:ListView ID="DeviceListView" runat="server" OnSorting="DeviceListView_Sorting"
                        OnItemCommand="DeviceListView_ItemCommand">
                        <LayoutTemplate>
                            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="color: Black;">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr style="background-color: #aed6f1;">
                                        <th align="left">
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkGroup" runat="server" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="ID">Group<br />Name</asp:LinkButton>
                                        </th>
                                        <th align="left" width="140">
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkName" runat="server" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="ID">Screen<br />Name</asp:LinkButton>
                                        </th>
                                        <th align="left" width="80">
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkStatus" runat="server" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="ID">Driver<br />Status</asp:LinkButton>
                                        </th>
                                        <th align="left" width="80">
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkLocalIPAddr" runat="server" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="ID">Local<br />IP Address</asp:LinkButton>
                                        </th>
                                        <th align="left" width="80">
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkRemoteIPAddr" runat="server" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="ID">Router<br />IP Address</asp:LinkButton>
                                        </th>
                                        <th align="left" width="80">
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSoftwareVersion" runat="server" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="ID">Software<br />Version</asp:LinkButton>
                                        </th>
                                        <th align="left" width="100">
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkTheme" runat="server" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="ID">Screen<br />Layout</asp:LinkButton>
                                        </th>
                                        <th align="left" width="80">
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkScreenType" runat="server" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="ID">Screen<br />Type</asp:LinkButton>
                                        </th>
                                        <th align="left" width="80">
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkScreenResolution" runat="server" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="ID">Screen<br />Resolution</asp:LinkButton>
                                        </th>
                                        <th width="40">
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <asp:DataPager ID="ItemDataPager" runat="server" PageSize="24">
                                <Fields>
                                    <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonCount="2" />
                                </Fields>
                            </asp:DataPager>
                        </LayoutTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTargetGroup"><b><%#Eval("TargetGroup")%></b></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTargetName"><b><%#Eval("TargetName")%></b></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblStatus" ForeColor='<%#Eval("StatusColour")%>'><b><%#Eval("Status")%></b></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblLocalIPAddr"><%#Eval("LocalIPAddr")%></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblRemoteIPAddr"><%#Eval("RemoteIPAddr")%></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblSoftwareVersion"><%#Eval("SoftwareVersion")%></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTheme"><%#Eval("Theme")%></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblScreenType"><%#Eval("ScreenType")%></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblScreenResolution"><%#Eval("ScreenResolution")%></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="min-width: 50px; max-width: 75px">
                                        <a href='../Device.aspx?id=<%#Eval("TargetID")%>'>
                                            <img class="img-responsive" src="Images/preview.png" /></a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1"><%#Eval("Target")%></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                            <tr style="background-color: #EFEFEF">
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTargetGroup"><b><%#Eval("TargetGroup")%></b></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTargetName"><b><%#Eval("TargetName")%></b></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblStatus" ForeColor='<%#Eval("StatusColour")%>'><b><%#Eval("Status")%></b></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblLocalIPAddr"><%#Eval("LocalIPAddr")%></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblRemoteIPAddr"><%#Eval("RemoteIPAddr")%></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblSoftwareVersion"><%#Eval("SoftwareVersion")%></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTheme"><%#Eval("Theme")%></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblScreenType"><%#Eval("ScreenType")%></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblScreenResolution"><%#Eval("ScreenResolution")%></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href='../Device.aspx?id=<%#Eval("TargetID")%>'>
                                        <img class="img-responsive voc_list_preview_img" src="Images/preview.png" /></a>
                                </td>
                                
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </AlternatingItemTemplate>
                    </asp:ListView>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="UpdateDevicesTimer" EventName="Tick"></asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger>
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
```

I would appreciate any help on this matter.

Comment: I am not sure if this can be done with your `asp:ListView` since it generates its own HTML structure which you have no control on and also which does not align good with the plugin recommended HTML structure. So this is not a easy task with this plugin if you ask me..

Comment: Thank you for answering. We are thinking of starting the table from the front end and then change the back-end code. It might be probably easier that way. ASP is driving me a bit crazy :)

Comment: yes that is a good choice.. then you have a lot of control on what can be done.. You can just request a JSON data from server and rest all can be done using Jquery..